# Is it "worth it" to reuse event variables in CUDA?

Tags: events, cuda

When using events in CUDA, I typically create an event and immediately record it on some stream. After synchronizing, I don't bother to hold on to that `cudaEvent_t`, to use it elsewhere - I just destroy it.

Other than avoiding the overhead of event creation and destruction, is there any other benefit to "recycling" events? If not, why did `nVIDIA` bother to separate `cudaEventCreate()` from `cudaEventRecord()` ?

Comment: Yes. A separated `create()` looks like a straight forward way to avoid the overhead of creation. Why do you think nVidia still need "other benefit" to make this design decision?

Comment: I'm believe that event creation is a synchronizing activity.  I'm reasonably sure that [event recording is not](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EVENT.html#group__CUDART__EVENT_1gf4fcb74343aa689f4159791967868446).   In a pipeline/processing loop, its desirable to avoid device-wide sync activity, for the same reasons that you wouldn't (shouldn't)  do cudaMalloc/cudaFree with reckless abandon in a performance-sensitive processing loop.

Comment: @kangshiyin: Because it doesn't seem like events should have any use, or incur any overhead, other than as regarding their `record()`ing.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: That's a bit strange to me - I mean, when you malloc, you give a parameter - the size; and this requires updating some host-side and maybe some device-side data structures. But saying "hey, event!" should not really do anything. At most you would think that you would have something like a `cudaSetMaxConcurrentEvents()` that you run once. Anyway, maybe that should be an answer.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of the synchronizing behavior of `cudaEventCreate`, it's not clearly documented.  It should be easy to construct a directed test to prove or disprove, however.  1. When in doubt, if the documentation doesn't say clearly, a cuda API call may be synchronizing.  2. `cudaEventRecord` clearly says it is async 3. I don't see how both processes could be async - the event itself is just a handle, but the creation process updates a table that the CUDA runtime must be able to refer to (even in other devices!).  Anyway, I could be wrong, it should be easy to test and prove/disprove.

Comment: It's also unclear what your definition of "overhead" is.  Even the synchronizing behavior of `cudaEventCreate` if it exists, is still ultimately just something that affects performance, and so could be considered "overhead" and thus is excluded by your question from the possible answer space.

Comment: So your real question is "what the overhead could be", rather than "is it worth it"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I'm trying to answer the question "what the overhead could be". As we don't have the source code of CUDA event. Everything is based on some reasonable guess. You could make totally different design decision to implement the CUDA event with same or similar behavior.

In the timing task we know that at least the time of the event is recorded somewhere. As the event happens on the device side, I think the time is recorded in the device side memory to avoid using PCIe (high overhead) during recording. As eventually you get the time from the host side, the recorded time must be transferred through PCIe at sometime (probably `eventSync()`).

You see during the whole procedure, you need some space both in host and device side memory to store the time. It looks good to me a perfect place to allocate/release the memory in `eventCreate()`/`eventDestroy()`, just like `malloc()`/`free()`. It also looks like a perfect overhead that you want to avoid when recording the time repeatedly (reusing the event).

So two types of overhead here, Allocating device and host space, and PCIe transfer. This is my guess. Maybe you could have another way to implement the timing functionality without involving these overheads.

Then finally, avoiding these overheads seems like a good reason that nVidia uses a separate `eventCreate()`.